# Uniformly Most Powerful test for a Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from the Pareto distribution with pdf
>
> $$f(x|\theta) =  \begin{cases} 
>       \theta x^{-(\theta+1)}, & x\geq 1 \\\
>       0, & 1 < x 
>    \end{cases}
> $$
>
> where $\theta > 0$ is unknown.
>
> Find a uniformly most powerful (UMP) test of size $\alpha$ for testing
>
> $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0$ versus 
>   $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$ where $\theta_0 > 0$ is a fixed real number.

Using Neyman-Pearson, the mp test is $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1, & \frac{f(\bf x, \theta_1)}{f(\bf x, \theta_0)} > k \\\
      0, & else 
   \end{cases} $

By solving for $\alpha = P_{H_0}(\sum_{ i = 1}^{n} \ln(X_i)) => 1- \alpha = P(2\theta\sum_{ i = 1}^{n} \ln(X_i) > 2\theta_0k) $

I get $k = \frac{1}{2\theta_0}\chi^2_{2n,1-\alpha}$

and $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1, & \sum_{ i = 1}^{n} \ln(X_i) < \frac{1}{2\theta_0}\chi^2_{2n,1-\alpha}  \\\
      0, & else 
   \end{cases} $

as the mp test.

I'm unsure how to go about showing whether this is the UMP test (rather than only MP). Any ideas? Also I'd really appreciate a comment on the correctness of the approach. I'm new to this sort of mathematics/statistics.

Comment: I think you should first verify whether the ratio $\frac{f_{\theta_2}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{f_{\theta_1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$ is non-decreasing in your sufficient statistic $\prod X_i$ (or $\sum \ln X_i$) for any $\theta_2>\theta_1$. If this is the case, then this pdf possesses the [MLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio#Most_powerful_tests:_The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem) property which would subsequently provide a UMP test.